# Check two pdf files and print if bigger than minimum size

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I have two pdf files which generated daily (from another part of the script using `wkhtmltopdf`) then batch will print this pdf if the size bigger than 9000byte. I have batch script below but only able to check for one pdf file. How to check for both pdf and print this file if meet minimum size?

File structure:

```
folder1\dailyreport1.pdf
folder2\dailyreport2.pdf
```

Batch script:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set file=folder1\dailyreport1.pdf
::set file=folder2\dailyreport2.pdf

set "minsize=9000"
    For %%I In (%file%)Do ( 
        set "size=%%~zI"
        if %%~zI LSS 9000 call :NOPRINT
        if %%~zI GTR 9000 call :PRINT
        )
    
:NOPRINT
echo Size %size% ^< %minsize%, skipped print %file%
goto SHUTDOWN

:PRINT
echo Size %size% ^> %minsize%, print %file%

:SHUTDOWN
echo shutdown.exe -s -t 600
PAUSE
```

Comment: `set "file=folder1\dailyreport1.pdf,file=folder2\dailyreport2"` and refactor the call and send `"%I"` to subroutines and use `"%~1"` in them

Comment: also, place `goto :eof` at the end of subroutines and shutdown (or whatever) after the loop

Comment: What happens if the file is exactly 9000 bytes big?

Comment: @elzooilogico noted, thank you for your suggestion. Will update my batch once i get back my laptop later in the morning.

Comment: @aschipfl for now, i checked all pdf are either less then 9kb (empty pdf with some header) or above 15kb (one line text plus header)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips and comment. Ended up im doing something like and dicthing the :`call` because cant get it working haha. Is it OK? Any comment/ improvement or another version much appreciated. Thank you.

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Exe1=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe"
set "file=folder1\dailyreport1.pdf, folder2\dailyreport2.pdf"

    For %%I In (%file%)Do ( 
        
        if %%~zI LSS 9000 Echo Skipped printing %%I
        if %%~zI GTR 9000 Echo Printing %%I &"%Exe1%" /p %%I
        )
echo shutdown.exe -s -t 600
PAUSE
```